# 'if' after assignment

Tags: perl, if-statement

What is the following line supposed to do in Perl?

```
$result{$key} .= ";" if (exists($result{$key}));
```

It looks like it adds ";" at the end of the key when it already exists. Is it true?

Is it different than putting the "if" statement before assigning?

Comment: You are right. And there is no difference. If you put the "if" in front you just have to put curly braces around the assignment.

Comment: Perl allows for post-`if` statements and also allows for post-`while`, and post-`for` loops too. However, these things are usually discouraged because people scanning the code may miss the `if`. Plus, if you realize you need to add another statement in the `if`, you have to rewrite the statement.

Comment: @DavidW.: . . . and post-`unless` and post-`until` :)

Comment: One advantage is that it allows you to use fewer parentheses: `$result{$key} .= ';' if exists $result{$key};`

Comment: I would generally avoid post statements, but make exceptions for `next unless ` or `return if` type constructs, because I consider the 'flow control' element important the more important one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perl allows you to do conditional statements either before or after.

This is to allow you to do things like:

```
return unless $configured;
exit if $bored;

print "Debug statement\n" if $debug;

while ( <STDIN> ) {
    print if m/text/;
}
```

So yes, you're right - that's a conditional append in that if the key exists, it'll stick a semicolon on the end of *the value*. (As noted in comments - it does *not* change the key.)

It isn't any different to:

```
if ( exists ( $result{$key} ) ) {
    $result{$key} .= ';';
}
```

Generally, it's a style and maintainability question as to which you use. I would *generally* suggest avoiding it, because it *generally* makes things less clear. (But not always - see above for a couple of examples.)

Comment: The OP is strictly *wrong* when he says, *“It looks like it adds ";" at the end of key when it already exists”* as the semicolon is added at the end of the hash *value*.

Comment: The official term (at least in *[Programming Perl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_Perl)*, p. 130 in one edition) for the post one is ***modifier*** (*statement modifier*?).

Answer (score 2):

1)  Could someone tell me what is this line supposed to do in perl:

```
$result{$key} .= ";" if (exists($result{$key}));
```

Answer:
The above expression can be read as

```
if ( exists ( $result{$key} ) ) {   
    $result{$key} .= ';';
}
```

Explanation:
if condition checks for existence of value obtained from the hash result(`%result`) with the key as `$key`, If the value exists then append the semicolon to the end of the value.

2) It looks like it adds ";" at the end of key when it already exists, is it true?

NO, Semicolon will be added to the end of the value and not at the end of the key, when it(value) exists, as value for a key is obtained from hash via
$hashName{$keyName}

Example:

```
C:\Users\kvivek>perl

my %fruit_color = (
    apple  => "red",
    banana => "yellow",
);

print $fruit_color{"apple"};
print "\n";
__END__
red

C:\Users\kvivek>
```

3)Is it different than putting "if" statement before assigning?

No, It is not different, but an another way writing.

Answer (score 1):

It's exactly as you said. It means:

> If the hash `%result` has an element with key `$key`, append `;` to the element's value.

because

```
$result{$key} .= ";" if (exists($result{$key}));
```

is just another way of writing

```
if ((exists($result{$key}))) {
    $result{$key} .= ";";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$result{$key} .= ";" if (exists($result{$key}));
```

and

```
if (exists($result{$key})) {
    $result{$key} .= ";";
}
```

do exactly the same thing. There are times where you may prefer one over another for better readability.

Answer (score 0):

```
$result{$key} .= ";" if (exists($result{$key}));
```

can be written as:

```
if (exists($result{$key}))
{
    $result{$key} .= ';';
}
```

There isn't any difference.