# I'm trying to find out if python has a feature. Probably not but I would really like if it does

Tags: python

I'm kind of new to python. in my code I have this statement.

`if foo < bar: bar = foo`

I know there is the := operator. I want to know if there is something that's somewhat of an inverse. instead of setting the variable and then testing it, is there something that will only set it if the check resolves to true? Or is that statement the simplest way to do that?

Comment: What you have is the simplest and most straight forward way to do what you have expressed, of only assigning to `bar` if a condition is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you're looking to call a function that has the right effect?

```
bar = min(bar, foo)
```

`min` still does an `if` statement internally, but this is more self-documenting than doing the `if` part yourself.

Comment: Note that this does not have the same effect of *assigning to `bar` __only__ if the condition is true…*

Comment: Thank you. For this case that works well. I've never heard of an operator like that in any language but it seems like something python would do so I was curious.

Comment: @CodyW Do you mean something like [this Perl construct](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28832661)?